# Create Json value with multiline

Tags: json, multiline

I have json file contains multi-keys and values.
I want one of the value to contain newline inside it.
I have tried more than one option as you can see in the following

```
{
 "ans": "first line \n second line \n third line",
 "ans1": "first line '\n' second line '\n' third line",
 "ans2": "first line '\\n' second line '\\n' third line",
 "ans3": ["Line one", "line Two", "Line Three"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals instead of string inverted commas, 
just use the back tick ( ` ) instead of inverted commas, its the key above the TAB key in your keyboard. then no need to use \n or anything if you're writing in template literals just press enter and it will consider it as a line break.

Answer (score 0):

JSON strings cannot include literal (i.e. unescaped) return or newline characters.

The usual way to specify a "newline character" in a JSON string is using the two-character sequence `\n`.

Thus in your sample JSON, .ans and .ans2 both contain two newline character specifications, whereas .ans2 has no newline character specifications, because the three-character subsequence `\\n` signifies a literal backslash following by the letter `n`.

If (for example) you wanted to "decode" .ans as a "raw" string (i.e., with literal newlines), you could use the command-line program, [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), like so:

```
$ jq -r .ans1 <<< "$json"
first line 
 second line 
 third line
```